# How to obfuscate Python code with buildpacks?

Tags: python-3.x, obfuscation, buildpack

I am using pack cli to build docker image for my **python** flask app running with gunicorn.

Inside docker image, my whole code is exposed in workspace folder.

*What shall i do to restrict user to access folder or obfuscate my code?*
I am using Google Buildpack

```
pack set-default-builder gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the Heroku Python Buildpack (and the `heroku/buildpacks:18` builder).

You can create a `bin/post_compile` and use it to run [compileall](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/compileall.html), and then run `rm **/*.py`

Comment: No, I have set the default builder to Google as Heroku is not using Ubuntu base image and it takes lot of time for building image(Building wheels for pandas). Anyways I will look on the link and see if I can achieve it